# Raspberry Pi suddenly stopped connecting to Wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have a raspberry pi 4 running rasbian OS that I am using to host a postgres database on a local network, but the device suddenly became unreachable and upon connecting the pi to an external display I can see that it is not connecting the the wifi. When I try to connect to the network nothing happens, no error message, it just doesn't connect.

What could be the reason for this / how could I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Your question implies the problem began after connecting the RPi to an external display? Is this RPi Desktop - or Lite?

Have you made any changes to your network configuration - or to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`?

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't totally clear, the problem started before connecting to the external display, I was unable to access the database hosted on the device so I connected it to an external display to troubleshoot, and from there I could see it wasn't connecting to the wifi. I have not made any changes to the network configuration, it seems like it just stopped working out of nowhere

Comment: @NicLovin: In that case, what's in the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`??  Could you (and can you still) connect to the RPi via SSH?